# FileIO.ReadTextAsync occasionally hangs

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm just experimenting with WinRT and one demo app i'm creating is a basic "notepad" style app which loads/saves to local storage. Whilst I'm familiar with the proper `async` approach for building WinRT apps, my demo app is using a synchronous `Load` to keep things simple.

The problem is that when a call is made to `Load`, it works 2 out of 3 times and the rest of the time the app hangs on the call `var result = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile);`

```
public class ContentStorage : IContentStorage
{
    private const string FileName = "contents.txt";

    public string Load()
    {
        return LoadAsync().Result;
    }

    public void Save(string content)
    {
        SaveAsync(content);
    }

    private static async Task<string> LoadAsync()
    {
        var storageFile = await LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(FileName);
        var result = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile);

        return result;
    }

    private static async void SaveAsync(string content)
    {
        var storageFile = await LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        FileIO.WriteTextAsync(storageFile, content);
    }

    private static StorageFolder LocalFolder
    {
        get { return ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder; }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something extraordinarily stupid here?

FWIW, I experimented with changing `Load` to just explicitly block on each step and this improves the hanging to 1 in 20, but I still don't understand why it's hanging at all...

```
public string Load()
{
    var storageFile = LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(FileName).AsTask().Result;
    var result = FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile).AsTask().Result;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You are not doing anything to ensure WriteTextAsync() completes.  Bad idea.

Comment: Hans, skipping the fact of the missing awaits keyword in front of the WriteTextAsync, what makes the **load** not to work as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Whilst I'm familiar with the proper `async` approach for building WinRT apps, my demo app is using a synchronous `Load` to keep things simple.

Not really. Mixing synchronous with asynchronous code is extremely complex. It's far simpler to just use `async` everywhere.

When an `async` method continues execution after waiting for a task, it will return to its original context by default. (I cover this in more detail in my [`async`/`await` blog post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)). Some contexts (such as UI contexts) only permit a single thread; if that thread is blocked (e.g., on `Task.Result`), then the `async` method cannot enter that context to complete its execution. This causes a deadlock.

For more information:

- The [`async`/`await` FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx) has a lot of detail on the context capture and resume.
- Stephen Toub on the Parallel Team Blog has another blog post [Await, and UI, and deadlocks! Oh, my!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx), which explains this particular deadlock situation in detail.
- I wrote an exhaustive answer for this kind of deadlock in [an MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/async/thread/269172a3-adb9-4b5e-9ac1-8b67ff920177#48b596cc-5eca-4d0e-8743-10d59b64e2ce).

This deadlock is famous enough that it's actually been demo'd by Microsoft:

- [By Stephen Toub at the BUILD conference (Sept 16, 2011).](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T)
- [By Lucian Wischik at DevConnections (Mar 26, 2012).](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2012/03/29/talk-async-part-1-the-message-loop-and-the-task-type.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ConfigureAwait(false`) with the await operation, may be `ReadTextAsync` is not thread safe, so it will hang the UI thread when the await finished and back to the UI thread.