# GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync seem to hang forever

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am trying to read data from a file, and the GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync, most of the times just hangs for ever, any ideas why that happens. I am debugging the app on the simulator.

A couple notes :

```
BaseLocalFolder = "ms-appdata:///local/";
Uri baseUri = new Uri(BaseLocalFolder);
Uri cardsUri = new Uri(baseUri, Path.Combine(set,"cards.ccc"));
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(cardsUri);

using (IInputStream stream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
{
    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(stream.AsStreamForRead()))
    {
        var cardArray = Windows.Data.Json.JsonArray.Parse(rdr.ReadToEnd());

        foreach (Tables.Card card in cardArray.ToCards())
        {
            _cards.Add(card.ToCardViewModel());
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATES:
After I changed the code according to suggestions, I started having the same issue with ReadTextAsync(), once it hits that line it stays there forever, I never get the string.

```
StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(Path.Combine(set, "cards.ccc"));

            try
            {

                string allCards = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

                var cardArray = Windows.Data.Json.JsonArray.Parse(allCards);
                foreach (Tables.Card card in cardArray.ToCards())
                {
                    _cards.Add(card.ToCardViewModel());
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException err)
            {
                string s = "";
            }
```

Comment: What's the value of `set` in `Path.Combine(set,"cards.ccc")` ?

Comment: Do you have any calls to `Wait` or `Result` further up your call stack?

Comment: @Xyroid The value could be one of many, Ex: "Dark Steel", "Alliance". Stephen, if I understood your question, this piece of code is wrapped in a async method, that I do wait, and there is not other code on the method besides what you see. The code executes till it hits the GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync and there it stays forever, I left over night and it never went through.

Comment: Are you getting any value in variable `file` ? Have you tried to use `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync(...)` & `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(...)` instead of `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(...)` ? cards.ccc seams to be JSON file, am I right ? To read cards.ccc, try `Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(...)`

Comment: @Xyroid I made the changes you suggested, now it hand on the ReadTextAsync, the files are about 300K, so it should not take that long to read.

Comment: Alright I found the reason, it hangs, its well explained [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700570/fileio-readtextasync-occasionally-hangs/12890801#12890801