# GetFileAsync freezes app and does not throws exception

Tags: c#, async-await, uwp

I'm trying to read a file with this:

```
public static async Task<JsonObject> read(string nome)
{
     nome = GetSafeFilename(nome);
     string json = "";
     try 
     {
           StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder; 
           Debug.WriteLine("here? folder");
           StorageFile jsonFile = await folder.GetFileAsync(nome);
           Debug.WriteLine("here? file");
           json = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(jsonFile);
           Debug.WriteLine("here? fileio" + json);
     }
     catch ( Exception ex )
     {
           Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
     }

     return JsonObject.Parse(json); //converte string para jsonobject
}
```

But the app freezes app and does not throw any exeption.
The "Console.Writeline" stops in "here? file".

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: the `async` keyword should be after `static` ..

Comment: ops. My mistake, but is not a solution..

Comment: If that were true, it wouldn't have compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to retrieve a information to an object that id binding. I did someArr = MyFile.getArray(filename).Result; and inside it has ... JsonObject json = await read(filename);

That's why your app freezes, it actually deadlocks when you call `Task.Result`. [You're blocking on async code.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Instead, you need to make your entire call chain async as well. This means that whichever code calls `read` should itself be `async` and return a `Task`:

```
public async Task ReadJsonAsync()
{
     var jsonObject = await MyFile.ReadAsync("foo");
}
```

Note C# naming conventions for methods are pascal case, and async methods should be added the "Async" postfix.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I changed the method to `static async public void getArr( MyObject my)` and making assignments within the asynchronous method. It works, but I do not know if it's a good technique.

Comment: @vinicius Not sure what that means

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine so the issue is quite likely in the method which calls the "read" method. Are you perhaps calling it synchronously, for example "read(myfile.json).Result? If so, you're quite likely encountering a deadlock.

Here's some discussion about the issue: [FileIO.ReadTextAsync occasionally hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700570/fileio-readtextasync-occasionally-hangs)

The best solution is to make sure that the you're not trying to mix async with synchronous calls.

Comment: I have to retrieve a information to an object that id binding. I did `someArr = MyFile.getArray(filename).Result;` and inside it has `... JsonObject json = await read(filename); ...`. Can you suggest me a other way to retrieve that data from file?